# inet_addr() returning the long for IP in reverse order

Tags: c++, windows, ip, winsock, wininet

I am trying to write a function to check if my ip is within subnet mask, as below: -

```
bool isIPinSubnet(CString ip, CString network, int keepbits)
{ 
 ULONG ip_addr      = 0;
 ULONG network_addr = 0;
UINT32 mask_addr     = ~(~(UINT32)(0) >> keepbits);

 ip_addr            = inet_addr(ip);
 network_addr   = inet_addr(network);

 ULONG net_lower = (network_addr & mask_addr);
 ULONG net_upper = (net_lower | (~mask_addr));
 if ( ip_addr >= net_lower && ip_addr <= net_upper ) {
     return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

Problem is its not working. On debugging, I saw that the inet_addr() function is returning the long for IP in reverse order.
For example, if I am doing this , `isIPinSubnet("192.168.0.15","192.168.0.1",24);`

the long inet_addr returns for `IP: 192.168.0.15` is `251701440`
and `IP: 192.168.0.1` is `16820416`.

Checking here http://www.smartconversion.com/unit_conversion/IP_Address_Converter.aspx

`251701440` corresponds to `IP: 15.0.168.192`, and

`16820416` corresponds to `IP: 1.0.168.192`
which clearly is the reverse of what we passed to inet_addr.

Why is this behaving this way? How to fix it?

Comment: Network byte order versus host byte order... From [the MSDN `inet_addr` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738563(v=vs.85).aspx): "All Internet addresses are returned in IP's network order"

Comment: See htonl or its friend ntohl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments by @Someprogrammerdude, on question,the issue is due to mismatch of Network byte order versus host byte order. To fix the problem in my code, we can use htonl and it works well.

```
bool isIPinSubnet(CString ip, CString network, int keepbits)
{ 
 ULONG ip_addr      = 0;
 ULONG network_addr = 0;
 UINT32 mask_addr     = ~(~(UINT32)(0) >> keepbits);

 ip_addr            = htonl (inet_addr(ip)); //Thanks to @ChrisBecke
 network_addr       = htonl (inet_addr(network));

 ULONG net_lower = (network_addr & mask_addr);
 ULONG net_upper = (net_lower | (~mask_addr));
 if ( ip_addr >= net_lower && ip_addr <= net_upper ) {
     return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```